# c# list FindAll predicate doesn't work

Tags: c#, delegates

Trying to write an predicate that finds families by the amount of kids and adults living in the home. Knowing that I can find the price for 1 square meter and find the amount it costs to clean up. However I can't make .FindAll work

```
     public void Find(List<PriceForCleaning> priceForCleaning)
    {
        int a = 0;
        foreach (var price in priceForCleaning)
        {
            List<Family> FalimiesBeingWorked = Families.FindAll(nn => nn.AmountOfKids == price.AmountOfKids && nn.AmountOfAdults == price.AmountOfAdults ? nn.HowMuchPayed = nn.AreaOfHome * price.OneSquareMeterCleaningPrice : 0);
        }
    }
```

The errors I get: 
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'
Error   2   Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Predicate' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Answer (score 0):

The `FindAll()` function accepts a **predicate.**

A predicate is of the form `public delegate bool Predicate<in T>( T obj )`.

So, your lambda expression must return a `bool`.

Instead, it returns an `int`.

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you cannot mix "finding families by the amount of kids and adults living in the home" ***and*** "finding the amount it costs to clean up."

First do one operation, then do the other.

Answer (score 0):

[FindAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) expects a predicate. Predicate returns `bool` by definition, which means your lambda has to return `bool` rather than performing computation.

```
var foundFamilies = Families.FindAll(nn => nn.AmountOfKids == 
          price.AmountOfKids && nn.AmountOfAdults == price.AmountOfAdults);
```

After you can perform computation for every element in `foundFamilies` collection.